# Is there a term limit for prime minister of Pakistan?

Tags: constitution, pakistan, prime-minister, election-requirements

Is there a maximum limit for the number of terms a person can serve as the Prime Minister of Pakistan?

Comment: I changed the answer as I found that the Wikipedia entry that equated the offices of President and Prime Minister for term limits was in error. The correction to the answer post has been made with the appropriate links. Wikipedia has been updated.

Comment: It hasn't been a problem: "I. I. Chundrigar of Muslim League had the shortest term of 55 days. Yousaf Raza Gilani of PPP had the longest consecutive term of 4 years and 86 days. At approximately 9 years and 215 days in total, Nawaz Sharif of PML (N) has been the longest-serving prime minister for a non-consecutive term. Sharif was re-elected for a third non-consecutive term on 5 June 2013, which is a record in the history of Pakistan. No prime minister of Pakistan has yet served their full five year term." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_ministers_of_Pakistan

Answer (score 11):

I originally misread the question to refer to the president of Pakistan.

The restrictions on the president and Prime Minister of Pakistan are set forth in the constitution of Pakistan. However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister_of_Pakistan#Eligibility)  said (in error)

> The incumbent Prime Minister is eligible for re-election to that
>   office, but cannot hold that office for more than two consecutive
>   terms.[29]

This has been changed and no longer says that. [Chapter III Article 91](http://pakistani.org/pakistan/constitution/part3.ch3.html) explicitly states that the only restriction is that the Prime Minister must be a member of the National Assembly or the Senate and that a new Prime Minister must be chosen after each national election. The constitution **explicitly** states that **there shall be no restriction on the number of terms for the office of the Prime Minister.**

> **91.     The Cabinet:**
>
> (1)   There shall be a Cabinet of Ministers, with the Prime Minister at
>   its head, to aid and advise the President in the exercise of his
>   functions.
>
> (2)   The National Assembly shall meet on the twenty-first
>   day following the day on which a general election to the Assembly is
>   held, unless sooner summoned by the President.
>
> (3)   After the
>   election of the Speaker and the Deputy Speaker, the National Assembly
>   shall, to the exclusion of any other business, proceed to elect
>   without debate one of its Muslim members to be the Prime Minister.
>
> (4)   The Prime Minister shall be elected by the votes of the majority
>   of the total membership of the National Assembly:
>
> Provided that, if no member secures such majority in the first poll, a
>   second poll shall be held between the members who secure the
>   two highest numbers of votes in the first poll and the member who
>   secures a majority of votes of the members present and voting shall be
>   declared to have been elected as Prime Minister:
>
> Provided further that, if the number of votes secured by two or more 
>   members securing the highest number of votes is equal, further
>   poll shall be held between them until one of them secures a majority
>   of votes of the members present and voting.
>
> (5)   The member elected under clause (4) shall be called upon by the
>   President to assume the office of Prime Minister and he shall, before
>   entering upon the office, make before the President oath in the form
>   set out in the Third Schedule:
>
> **Provided that there shall be no restriction on the number of terms for the office of the Prime Minister.**
>
> (6)   The Cabinet, together with the Ministers of State, shall be
>   collectively responsible to the Senate and the National Assembly.
>
> (7)   The Prime Minister shall hold office during the pleasure of the
>   President, but the President shall not exercise his powers under this
>   clause unless he is satisfied that the Prime Minister does not command
>   the confidence of the majority of the members of the National
>   Assembly, in which case he shall summon the National Assembly and
>   require the Prime Minister to obtain a vote of confidence from the
>   Assembly.
>
> (8)   The Prime Minister may, by writing under his hand
>   addressed to the President, resign his office.
>
> (9)   A Minister who
>   for any period of six consecutive months is not a member of the
>   National Assembly shall, at the expiration of that period, cease to be
>   a Minister and shall not before the dissolution of that Assembly be
>   again appointed a Minister unless he is elected a member of that
>   Assembly:
>
> Provided that nothing in this clause shall apply to a Minister who is a 
>   member of the Senate.
>
> (10)  Nothing in this Article shall be construed as disqualifying
>   the Prime Minister or any other Minister or a Minister of State for
>   continuing in office during any period during which the National
>   Assembly stands dissolved, or as preventing the appointment of any
>   person as Prime Minister or other Minister or a Minister of State
>   during any such period.

**Original post which actually refers to the president:**

The answer to your question depends on how the government of Pakistan reads the phrase "two consecutive terms". This can be read to mean that after two terms (10 years), the President must allow someone else to serve for one term (similar to the way Grover Cleveland was President of the United States for two nonconsecutive terms). It can also be read to mean that he is forbidden to serve as President again after a period that would constitute two consecutive terms (10 years), similar to the way a President of the United States cannot serve for more than 10 years as President even if they are not consecutive. Note that the United States allows for the case of a Vice President filling out the term of a deceased president and then being elected for two terms on his own.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister_of_Pakistan#Eligibility)  says

> The incumbent Prime Minister is eligible for re-election to that
>   office, but cannot hold that office for more than two consecutive
>   terms.[29]
>
> 44    **Term of office of President.**
>   (1)   Subject to the Constitution, the
>   President shall hold office for a term of five years from the day he
>   enters upon his office:
>
> Provided that the President shall, notwithstanding the expiration of his
>   term, continue to hold office until his successor enters upon his office.
>
> (2)   Subject to the Constitution, a person holding office as
>   President shall be eligible for re-election to that office, but no
>   person shall hold that office for more than two consecutive terms.
>
> (3)   The President may, by writing under his hand addressed to the
>   Speaker of the National Assembly, resign his office.

Comment: This answer refers to the post of president, but the question is about the prime minister.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff I fixed the post

Answer (score 4):

There is no restrictions on the number of terms for the office of the Prime Minister in Pakistan. 
Anybody who is eligible as dictated in the **Constitution of Pakistan** can become the Prime Minister of Pakistan multiple times; no number of term restricted. In 2013, **Mr. Nawaz Sharif** was elected Prime Minister of Pakistan for a third term.

Answer (score -2):

There is no term limit of democratically elected government in Pakistan. Even there is no future of democracy in Pakistan. There is very strong rationale about this.

The birth of Pakistan itself based on the religious divide. When Pakistan formed in 1947 there were many communities and religions in Pakistan but gradually they became minorities and Pakistan completely dominated by religious leadership.

In fact past army rules which took over always on democratic elected government in Pakistan led was based in fulfilling desire of Pakistani religious agenda.

All we can say there are only two options left for Pakistan either they will not be anymore in world's map in coming future or they volunteer merged their country with India and ask apology for 1947.

Comment: Please focus on answering the question only. The only sentence which addresses the question is the first. The rest goes onto a tangent which wasn't asked for.

Answer (score -5):

There is no term limit for the Prime Minister of Pakistan. He can be elected multiple times.

Comment: To further improve your answer, can you please provide with more details, like links to some official documents?